# Проблема с привязкой контекста

Tags: javascript

Как привязать контекст в данной ситуации:

```js
{
  "use strict";
  const field = document.querySelector('.wrapper'),
    startGame = document.querySelector('#startGame');

  class TicTacToe {
    constructor() {
      this.started = false;
      this.count = 0;
    }

    start(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.started = true;
      const createField = document.createElement('table');
      createField.classList.add('tic-tac-toe');
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          const td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        createField.appendChild(tr);
      }
      field.innerHTML = '';
      field.appendChild(createField);

      createField.addEventListener('click', e => {
        game.move(e); // !! Если обращаться к this, то он равен createField
        this.move(e);
      });
    }

    move(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.count)
    }
  }

  const game = new TicTacToe();

  startGame.addEventListener('click', game.start, {
    capture: true
  });
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.tic-tac-toe {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tic-tac-toe td {
  border: 2px solid rgb(26, 26, 26);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="startGame">Начать!</button>
</div>
```

Пробовал `.call`, не помогло.

Восклицательными знаками показана проблемная строчка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не `createField` там `this`, а кнопка "Начать".

```
  startGame.addEventListener('click', function(e) { game.start(e); }, {
    capture: true
  });
```